# How to pass parameter value in function nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to pass the value of the parameter after the function is created. Here I want to pass the `path` parameter value into for loop. Please check the second place where I am trying to access the function and then pass the value of the parameter.

I want to create a mock server client from the first function and then make a call to the backend at a specific path.

**Check Below from the library mockServerClient package.**

```
/**
     * Start the client communicating at the specified host and port
     * for example:
     *
     *   var client = mockServerClient("localhost", 1080);
     *
     * @param host the host for the server to communicate with
     * @param port the port for the server to communicate with
     * @param path the path if server was deployed as a war
     */
    mockServerClient = function (host, port, path) {
        

        /**
         * The default headers added to to the mocked response when using mockSimpleResponse(...)
         */
        var defaultResponseHeaders = [
            {"name": "Content-Type", "values": ["application/json; charset=utf-8"]},
            {"name": "Cache-Control", "values": ["no-cache, no-store"]}
        ];
        var defaultRequestHeaders = [];
```

**outside for loop**

```
const client = mockServerClient('localhost', '8080');
```

**inside for loop makes a call to the backend at a specific path.**

```
var array = [path1, path2, .....]; // array of some path

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  //here I want pass the path
   client.passValueOfParameter as path 
   this client will make some call backend call..
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the value of parameter"? Can you be more specific? Also in the loop, you are overriding the `client` variable in every iteration

Comment: @Neelabh Singh, Can you explain your question? It is not clear what you want to ask.

Comment: @TomaszStaszkiewicz. I want to create a mock server client from the first function and then make a call to the backend at a specific path.

Comment: @DipanshuMahla. I want to create a mock server client from the first function and then make a call to the backend at a specific path.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you want to create a mock server client from the first function and then make a call to the backend at a specific path.

*`If I am wrong then please comment it out`*

A simple 'Client' class will do the job.

```
class Client {
    constructor(host, port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    call(path) {
        // code to send the request
    }
}
```

You can simply create a client object and call the 'call' function to send the request.

```
const paths = [path1, path2, ...path3];
const client = new Client('localhost', 8080);

// using 'path' package to join the paths
client.call(path.join(paths));
```

Comment: You understand question correctly, could you answer in nodejs

Comment: @NeelabhSingh this is in node.js

Comment: var client = function (host, port, path) {
     //some code
     return client_var;
}
// Above from the library mockServerClient package.

Comment: I checked, and that library provides the functionality I just wrote in this answer.

Comment: please check it agian

Comment: check it https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockserver-client#:~:text=mockserver%2Dnode.-,Setup%20Expectation,-A%20simple%20expectation

Comment: anyhow even if it didn't provided anything, you can simply create a mockServerClient in Client class and use it to call